# save image in a directory in applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I was trying to save an imagefile to a directory in applicationStorageDirectory of my air project. Created the directory first

```
 var imageDirectory:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("vispics");

   if (imageDirectory.exists)
   {
       Alert.show("Directory Already Exists");

   }
   else {
       imageDirectory.createDirectory();
       Alert.show(imageDirectory.nativePath);
   }
```

The next part is saving image from my cam right now it saves to the applicationStorageDirectory. Here is how i do it

```
     var randInt:int = Math.random() * (99999 - 1001) + 1001;
      var randStr:String = randInt.toString();
      var filename:String = ""+randStr+".jpg";


        var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( filename );
        var wr:File = new File( file.nativePath );
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open( wr , FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeBytes ( imageData, 0,imageData.length );
        stream.close();
```

Is there a way that i can store the image in my "vispics" directory? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("vispics/" + filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping a flex beginner

Comment: There is also a File.separator static property that will give you the proper path separator: ("vispics" + File.separator + filename)

Comment: @JoeWard - Yes, that property is available, and will work, but it's not intended for that.  As per the [documentation for the resolvePath() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?#resolvePath()): _"You should always use the forward slash (/) character as the path separator. On Windows, you **can** also use the backslash (\) character, but you should not."_  The `separator` property **can** be used, but it is more intended for searching paths.  The "proper path separator" relative to this method is always the forward slash.