# url request application storage directory AS3 Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, urlrequest

I have an application prepared in Action Script 3. There is a part related to requesting a file from application storage directory. However when I use following codes (xmlLoader part), program looks into app directory.

How can I make it look into application storage directory or may any other code alternatives be used for this request? Thanks.

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(Puzzleoriginalpath + ".xml"));
```

Comment: What is Puzzleoriginalpath?

Comment: Puzzleoriginalpath was set before this code and it is for example puzzles/puzzle1/examplepuzzle
And this path is in app-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the storage directory through

```
 File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath
```

Then build your path:

```
 File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath + "/examplepuzzle.xml"
```

Comment: Definately! I didn't think that appstorage directory and file path can be added with plus :/ Thank you!

Comment: You can use `resolvePath` like
`var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("examplepuzzle.xml");`

check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858670/save-image-in-a-directory-in-applicationstoragedirectory