# AS3: How to take JPG / PNG screenshot and save it to SDCard directories of Android mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, screenshot

I made an Android mobile app by taking a screenshot and saving it into JPG / PNG format and saved to directory SDCard / Internal storage on android mobile.

When I tried it on desktop all went right with no problem. After I publish and install the `.apk` into mobile Android, if I hit save button iI get an error like this

> "Unfortunately, My application has stopped."

Can anyone help me about this error?

This my code :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

btn_save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_image);
function save_image(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   btn_back.visible = false;
   btn_save.visible = false;
   var qImageData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(540, 960);
   qImageData.draw(stage);
   var qEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
   var qBytes:ByteArray = qEncoder.encode(qImageData);
   var qfile:FileReference = new FileReference();
   var names:String = "Image_name";
   qfile.save(qBytes, names+".jpg");
   btn_back.visible = true;
   btn_save.visible = true;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Quote: *The save() method first opens an operating-system dialog box that asks the user to enter a filename and select a location on the local computer to save the file.* I don't think Android has such a thing as dialog box. You should use **File** and **FileStream** classes instead.

Comment: thanks for your response, can you give me an example in a coding or link which part of the above code should I fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858670/save-image-in-a-directory-in-applicationstoragedirectory

Comment: Check the updated info in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crashing because of a **permissions** issue (not allowed to write data to device). 
Research how to allow such permissions via AIR/AS3 or coding tool (IDE) options for output.

Also consider:

- Adding `import flash.net.FileReference;`.
- Make sure variables are declared outside of functions. 
  Otherwise that `var qfile:FileReference` will only begin to exist when function is triggered. That's fine for Flash Player on desktop, but on mobile your app has to talk to Android OS where that OS might not like some (previously) undeclared file-system editing variable that suddenly appears within a function...
- `:FileReference` brings up a "Save As" dialog on desktop, how does that work on mobile device? Maybe you should (as expected) use AIR's `FileSystem` API to make a `:File` type for automatically saving to SD card when "save" button is clicked?
- Check these [**search results**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bair%5D+android+file+save) for hints about how others do it.

**(Updated code)** : Untested but first try setting code like below...
 (If does not work then research permissions issue, also try`File` instead of `FileReference`)

```
//## 1) add imports
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

import flash.net.FileReference; //add this

//## 2) declare variables
var names:String = "Image_name";
var qImageData:BitmapData;
var qEncoder:JPGEncoder;
var qBytes:ByteArray;
//var qfile:FileReference = new FileReference();
var qFile:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(names+".jpg");
var qFStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

//## 3) add any required listeners
btn_save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_image);

//## 4) declare all functions here onwards
function save_image(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    btn_back.alpha = 0.4; //btn_back.visible = false;
    btn_save.alpha = 0.4; //btn_save.visible = false;
    qImageData = new BitmapData(540, 960);
    qImageData.draw(stage);
    qEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    qBytes = qEncoder.encode(qImageData);

    //var qfile:FileReference = new FileReference();
    //var names:String = "Image_name";
    //qfile.save(qBytes, names+".jpg");

    qBytes.position = 0;
    qFStream.open(qFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    qFStream.writeBytes(qBytes, 0, qBytes.length);
    qFStream.close();
    btn_back.alpha = 0.4; //btn_back.visible = true;
    btn_save.alpha = 0.4; //btn_save.visible = true;

    //## Check if file (qFile) was created successfully (it exists on SD card)
    if (qFile.exists) 
    {
        //# Do something if "The File Exists" on the SD card...

    }
    else
    {
        //# Here will handle case of "No File Created"...

    }

}
```

Also make sure your [**Android manifest allows**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html) the `WRITE` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It will be a file named `app.xml` or `YourFileName-app.xml`. Make sure it's something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">

  <id>author.YourFileName</id>

  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>

  <versionLabel/>

  <filename>YourFileName</filename>

  <description/>

<!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->

  <name>YourFileName</name>

  <!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->

  <copyright/>

  <initialWindow>
    <content>YourFileName.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
  </initialWindow>

  <icon>
    <image72x72>My_Assets/icons/YourFileName_icon_72.png</image72x72>
    <image48x48>My_Assets/icons/YourFileName_icon_48.png</image48x48>
    <image36x36>My_Assets/icons/YourFileName_icon_36.png</image36x36>
  </icon>

  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>

  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>

  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>

      <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>

</application>
```

Comment: Thanks VC.One you've taught me about writing the correct code, I've replaced FileReference to FileStream but when I run it on android, btn_save can not open the android mobile directory file and nothing happens to save that screenshot into JPG. can you help me once more how to make the codenya?

Comment: @IWayanArthana I'm not on a computer with Flash so I can't test any code before replying. Give me some hints... (1) Do you get any error messages when trying to save? (2) Can you be sure nothing happens? I mean clicking the `save_btn` should start a silent save process (file just appears inside target folder), so check your target folder... (3) I suggest you [**`Edit your Question`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47003420/edit) to show what code you used. Will be easier to check for problems. Thanks

Comment: thank you for teaching me and helping me very well, sorry I am late to reply to your comments and I will try your suggestion